# Python - Is having a child class reference parent class information appropriate?

Tags: python, class, parent-child

I'm working on an API for building an AI for a specific turn based strategy game. I'm planning to have a `Game` class which keeps general information about the game including things like the layout of the map (the map will be different each time and will have "terrains" that need to be taken into account). Then, I would like the `Game` class to contain a list of another `Unit` class. This is a list of the units that are currently on the game's map. Then I would like the `Unit` class to have a function like `canMove` which given a location will check if the unit can move to that place on the map or not. So here I have a situation where the `Unit` needs to look at its parent's (the `Game`'s) map information.

One approach to accomplishing this would be for the `Unit` to remember its parent `Game` and reference its map information when necessary. This would work, however, this seems a bit cyclical and I don't know that it seems the most appropriate to program it this way.

Another approach would be to, instead of having a `Unit.canMove` function, have a `Game.unitCanMove` function. However, this approach seems more complex from the API's user point of view and that doesn't seem right to me either.

Is there a more appropriate way to do this in general? Am I just being overly worried about the these methods? Any other suggestions? Thank you much!

Comment: I think `Unit` subclassing `Game` in this context is perfectly acceptable, personally.

Comment: @That1Guy: Hell no. A Unit is not a Game, and this is a has-a relationship anyway, not an is-a relationship.

Comment: @EMS: I think what you're suggesting sounds the most reasonable. But wouldn't the `Game` just end up being that controller layer you're discussing? And the `Map` would just be a class that's also watched by this controller `Game` class? Or are you talking about a controller in some other way? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's fine to have a central controller, I just mean you might want some class or classes that do nothing but encapsulate game state, some other class or classes that do nothing but control representations of the game state (visual, text-based, print outs, whatever), and some other class or classes that encapsulate the logical elements of the game that you want to model (pieces, rules, whatever). Then the central controller is responsible for mutating the state of the game by modifying the state-holders whenever it is signaled to do so by the game elements.

Comment: @user2357112 Wow, thanks for going internet on me. I misread the question...

Comment: @EMS: Great. And in such a case, the only real way to do that would be for each of the encapsulated classes to have a reference to the central controller, similar to my first suggested approach, right? As in the `Unit` would need to tell the central controller "hey, I need the map data", correct? Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, EMS, write an answer so we can upvote it :)

Comment: @EMS: As Kigurai said, if you could compile your comments into an answer, it would be great.